# Oracle PLSQL long run issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

there is long run issue with below code kindly help to rectify this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
Declare
l_status varchar2(10);

Begin

Insert into @table_name (ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM, CUST_SROGT_ID, TRD_REF_NUM, CNTRY_CD)
  Select ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM, CUST_SROGT_ID, TRD_REF_NUM, CNTRY_CD 
           from {{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} partition ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}});

Commit;

For i in ( Select mfu_source.Customer_Surrogate_ID CUST_SROGT_ID, Agg.TRD_REF_NUM TRD_REF_NUM, mfu_source.Enterprise_Customer_ID ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM
          from {{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} partition ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}}) AGG,
          {{sourceTableLatest('mfu_table')}} partition ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('mfu_table')}}) mfu_source
         Where (mfu_source.TA_LINK_ID=AGG.TRD_REF_NUM or mfu_source.TRANSACTION_ID=AGG.TRD_REF_NUM)
         and trim(AGG.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM) is null) 
         Loop
         
         
    Update @table_name set ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM= i.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM where TRD_REF_NUM=i.TRD_REF_NUM;
    
    Commit;
End Loop;

END;
```

the above code take long run issue need to rectify the issue with simple and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `MERGE` statement (rather than multiple statements in a loop):

```sql
Declare
  l_status varchar2(10);
Begin
  Insert into @table_name (ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM, CUST_SROGT_ID, TRD_REF_NUM, CNTRY_CD)
  Select ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM, CUST_SROGT_ID, TRD_REF_NUM, CNTRY_CD 
  from   {{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} partition ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}});

  MERGE INTO @table_name dst
  USING (
    Select mfu_source.Customer_Surrogate_ID CUST_SROGT_ID,
           Agg.TRD_REF_NUM TRD_REF_NUM,
           mfu_source.Enterprise_Customer_ID ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM
    from   {{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} partition ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}}) AGG
           INNER JOIN {{sourceTableLatest('mfu_table')}} partition ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('mfu_table')}}) mfu_source
           ON    mfu_source.TA_LINK_ID     = AGG.TRD_REF_NUM
              or mfu_source.TRANSACTION_ID = AGG.TRD_REF_NUM
    Where  trim(AGG.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM) is null
  ) src
  ON dst.TRD_REF_NUM = src.TRD_REF_NUM
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET dst.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM = src.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM;

  Commit;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop, you can run it with a single UPDATE statement. Apart from that, you should switch to modern (well, it exists for more than 20 years) ANSI join syntax.

```
UPDATE @table_name SET ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM = ( 
    SELECT mfu_source.Enterprise_Customer_ID 
        FROM {{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} PARTITION ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}}) AGG
            JOIN {{sourceTableLatest('mfu_table')}} PARTITION ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('mfu_table')}}) mfu_source ON mfu_source.TA_LINK_ID = AGG.TRD_REF_NUM OR mfu_source.TRANSACTION_ID = AGG.TRD_REF_NUM
    WHERE TRIM(AGG.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM) IS NULL 
        AND TRD_REF_NUM = Agg.TRD_REF_NUM)
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 'x' 
        FROM {{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} PARTITION ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}}) AGG
            JOIN {{sourceTableLatest('mfu_table')}} PARTITION ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('mfu_table')}}) mfu_source ON mfu_source.TA_LINK_ID = AGG.TRD_REF_NUM OR mfu_source.TRANSACTION_ID = AGG.TRD_REF_NUM
    WHERE TRIM(AGG.ENTRP_CUST_ID_NUM) IS NULL 
        AND TRD_REF_NUM = Agg.TRD_REF_NUM)
```

Comment: WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 'x' - means which fields it refers?

Comment: Nothing, it just checks if a record exist. If you don't put this condition, then records which have no matches in `@table_name` would be updated with `NULL`.

Comment: the above update statement i have tried but facing error 
Error in ActionStatement
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at line 9

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT mfu_source.Enterprise_Customer_ID ...`. If you still get the error, then review your data and decide which one shall be used for update.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit thank you for the solution.can you please explain because i admit is for the first time when i see something like that in Oracle
{{sourceTableLatest('Aggregation[table]')}} PARTITION ({{getSourcePartitionNameLatest('Aggregation[table]')}}) AGG
What actually do?
Thank you

Comment: @Florin I assume the code is generated dynamically, `{{ }}` is used as template, e.g. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit thank you for the answer and also for provide the documentation